# Is "knowledge *at* photography?" correct grammatically?

Tags: grammaticality

> Do you have any knowledge *at* photography?

Is this sentence correct? I don't think so, the *at* doesn't sound right, but my friend says some grammar checker tells that its correct?

Comment: One of the easiest things to do is to check dictionaries for usage: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knowledge) | [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/knowledge) | [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knowledge) to see what their examples use in similar sentences. They are all *knowledge **of.*** Also, it would be useful to know what "some grammar checker" actually was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

I think this is better:

"Do you have any knowledge of photography?"

or this variation feels more natural to me:

"Do you know anything about photography?"

Comment: Exactly..that's what I was thinking. But do you know why that grammar checker didn't catch it?

Comment: @Sawarnik: Software "grammar checkers" are largely a waste of time.  This particular preposition usage doesn't meaningfully adhere to any "rules" anyway - it's just established idiomatic preference that native speakers tend to use ***of, concerning, about, regarding,*** in constructions involving *have **knowledge** [preposition] **[subject]***. Things would change if we replaced *knowledge* with *experience, information,* but this goes way beyond what dumb software could be expected to handle.

Comment: Well, "knowledge at" can work in some contexts: "His general knowledge at times seemed limitless".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yup, thanks :) I knew I was right :)

Comment: As to why the dumb machine told you it was OK: maybe - just guessing - there's a script there telling the machine that if there's a question about a field of expertise (photography, physics, etc.), it's got to be a question concerning "being good AT sth". Or your friend's BSing you :)

Answer (score -1):

Possible:

> Do you have any knowledge about photography?